# Как правильно говорить "ногти разного цвета" или "ногти разных цветов"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Допускается ли первый вариант или это разговорная форма?

Answer (score 2):

Хуже как раз второй вариант. Хоть в десять цветов выкрасьте – все равно будут ногти разного цвета. Просто так принято говорить.

Comment: второе двусмысленно, потому как есть понятие цветы. и у них тоже есть ногти.
Ноготки.
а поэтому первая фраза наиболее точна.

Answer (score 2):

Розенталь:

**разный – различный совпадают в значениях**:

1)всякий, всевозможный, **разнообразный**;

2)**неодинаковый**, непохожий;

слово "различный" сильнее подчеркивает непохожесть, своеобразие; ср.: *разные точки зрения – различные точки зрения*.

Только "разный" употребляется в значении "иной, другой, не один и тот же": *разошлись в разные стороны*.

Так что по значению обе предложенные формы совпадают.

Но думаю, что правильно **"ногти разного цвета"**.

Правило:

Единственное число употребляется в значении множественного при указании на то, что одинаковые предметы принадлежат каждому лицу или предмету из целой их группы или находятся в одинаковом отношении к ним (так называемое дистрибутивное значение), например: *Солдаты стояли с опущенной головой*... (Пушкин); *Ученики писали карандашом* (не «карандашами»).

У каждого солдата голова, у каждого ученика карандаш, у каждого ногтя цвет, а не цвета. "Ногти разных цветов" - это когда каждый ноготь разноцветный, выкрашен в несколько цветов.

Answer (score 2):

Полностью согласен с Тат. Однако, если предположить, что некоторые девушки красят один ноготь в разные цвета, то вполне возможно сказать: ***ногти разных цветов.***

Comment: Ногти разного цвета - один белого цвета, другой красного цвета. Если один ноготь покрашен в разные цвета - он просто разноцветный. Ногти разных цветов - это применение разнообразных цветов при оформлении ногтей.

Comment: Серж, непонятно, кто ставит Вам минус за мнение по спорной теме. Я его убираю

Comment: Да, София, спасибо.

Comment: Есть у меня некие подозрения насчет минусов... Скучно кому-то, дай влеплю десяток минусов с мульта.))) Было такое уже года два назад.
Я просил тогда сделать минусы явными, с указанием, кто его поставил - не поняли...  
Если что, я минусы не ставил, хотя не согласен. Со всеми.)))

Comment: behemothus, а у вас есть какое-то мнение насчет этой темы. Я вчера просматривал материалы на эту тему, в текстах встречаются оба варианта, причем не только по отношению к ногтям, а например, к глазам. Глаза разного цвета; глаза разных цветов.

Comment: мнение написал, зловреда нашел.)))
http://russ.hashcode.ru/users/1931/fatyalink/reputation/

По поводу глаз: да, я видел. Не стал сразу писать. Но если интересно.  
Гугл: "глаза разного цвета" - 39000 
Гугл: "глаза разных цветов" - 3000  
Чего я и ожидал.

Comment: А как вам удалось найти???

Comment: Интуиция)))
Говорю ж, два года назад уже разбирался с этой манерой. 
А то, что это оно, не сомневайтесь, там -1 в уважении ставится за каждый минус.

Answer (score 0):

Выражения имеют разный смысловой оттенок:

(1) Ногти разного (различного) цвета. Смысловой акцент делается на  том, что ногти покрашены не в одинаковый, а в разный цвет.

(2) Ногти разных цветов - это просто разноцветные ногти. Например: "Ногти разных цветов – популярный и очень интересный вариант окрашивания".

(3) Если один ноготь выкрашен в разные цвета, то он разноцветный. Выражение "ногти разных цветов" не может передать этот смысл.

И ПРО ГЛАЗА

Глаза разного цвета - это два разных глаза, например голубой и черный.

Глаза разных цветов - это означает  "пестрые" глаза, с набором различных красок (например зеленый, голубой, рыжий окрас каждого глаза). Но так обычно не говорят, так как смысл неясен.

Сравнить: глаза имеют разный цвет - голубой и черный (но не разные цвета).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 03.10.14

Вариант 1. Предметы разного/одного цвета? Цвет (ед.ч.) одного предмета сравнивается с цветом других предметов. Вариант  применяется, (1) когда все предметы имеют обязательно отличаются друг от друга по цвету. Вариант применяется, (2) когда мы  описываем ситуацию сравнения: предметы не одного, а разного цвета.

Например: "Ньютон понял, что обычный дневной свет является смесью лучей разного цвета ― от красного до фиолетового". "Правда, на свидания он обычно приходил в ботинках разного цвета и без шнурков".

Вариант 2. Предметы разных цветов (мн.ч.) - фиксируется разнообразная окраска. Это общая оценка, ситуация сравнения не рассматривается.

Например: У мощной стены ― три типа охраны в форме разных цветов и фасонов. Елочки разных цветов: зеленые, белые, желтые…

Comment: >И ПРО ГЛАЗА  
Неверно. C таким же успехом можно утверждать наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Выражения абсолютно тождественны  по смыслу.
Слово "разный" уже предполагает как минимум два объекта и если "цвет" *разный*, то это как минимум два цвета. Так что правильно и "разного цвета" и "разных цветов."

Все остальные соображения считаю надуманными, не вижу причин искать какие-то скрытые акценты. Единственное: логично ожидать, что из двух вариантов говорящий выберет форму единственного числа как наиболее простую. Так, по моим наблюдениям, обычно и происходит.

А вообще лучше всего сказать ***разноцветные ногти***. И никаких проблем.

Comment: Мы купили десять шаров разных цветов - красные, синие, зеленые, желтые. Мы купили десять шаров разного цвета (они все должны быть различного цвета).

Comment: София, не понял. А к чему это?
И само утверждение ("они все должны быть различного цвета") спорно и объяснение "разный" через "различный" не полно. Но главное, не вижу никакого отношения к моей мысли.

Comment: Я думаю, что выражения НЕ ТОЖДЕСТВЕННЫ по смыслу: разного цвета - неодинаковые, а разных цветов - разноцветные. Именно поэтому чаще говорят, что глаза разного цвета, а не разных цветов.

Comment: >Я думаю, что выражения НЕ ТОЖДЕСТВЕННЫ   
Тогда разницу поясните как-то попонятнее. А то у вас все примеры можно понимать "с точностью до наоборот".
"Разноцветный" - это и один ***разного цвета***, и два - тоже разного, хотя каждый из двух - одного. Вы одно спорное утверждение аргументируете другим, еще более спорным.  
Радуга - она "разноцветная"? "Разных цветов"? "Разного цвета"? По мне так все верно. А конфетти?

Comment: Радуга - только разноцветная, конфетти - только разноцветное, потому что это ЕДИНИЧНЫЕ предметы. Разного цвета или разных цветов могут быть ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ, из которых они состоят. Конфетти однозначно состоит из кружочков РАЗНЫХ (разнообразных)  ЦВЕТОВ (цвета повторяются). Про радугу следует сказать, что она состоит из полос РАЗНОГО (различного) ЦВЕТА (они не повторяются,  из полос разных цветов - это семантическая неточность).

Comment: Форма ед.числа используется в том случае, если нужно подчеркнуть, что все составляющие элементы имеют различный, неповторяющийся цвет. Мы же говорим: эти два шара имеют разный цвет, а не разные цвета.

Comment: вот упертый, цвет не разный, а разного цвета, свет. Множество цветов, вот и отличи, краска это или растений масса.
Финита ля комедия.

Comment: fatyalink, Не переходите на личности. Рано вам еще.))  
София, я правильно понимаю, что для вас уже не две, а "три большие разницы"? "Разноцветные, разного цвета и разных цветов" - все разное? Тогда тем более столько не выпью. Вы посмотрите, "разноцветные", "разного цвета" и "разных цветов" используется по отношению глазам почти исключительно для обозначения ситуации, когда один одного цвета, другой - другого. И никого в философию подобную вашей не тянет. Я понимаю, что статистика - не лучшее доказательство, но другого здесь быть не может. Или ваш вариант кем-то из лингвистов обоснован?